# what do i do if a c# error says " operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of the type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3' "

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm trying to scrip for my first person controller in unity. Everything is good except for this one line

```
Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y * transform.right * currentDir.x) * walkSpeed * Vector3.up * velocityY;
```

and it wont let me save it

Comment: What about the error message is unclear to you?

Comment: You can't multiply two vectors together. (You might be able to multiply one with a number?)

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to multiply those vectors together. Not the dot product, cross product, nor a component-wise product produce anything useful in the way you've written the formula here. In short, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). Why not explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot multiply vectors together with `*`, as that is a scalar operation. You can multiply a vector by a scalar, which means to increase its magnitude, but a multiplication of vectors with the `*` scalar operator does not make sense.
You need to use a dotProduct with [Vector3.Dot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) or a crossProduct with [Vector3.Cross](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) depending of what you want to do.

Take into account that `transform.forward` and `transform.up` are the local axis of your gameObject in the world's coordinate system, so they are vectors. Same as `Vector3.up` which is (0,1,0). So if you chain a any of those with `*`, that should not compile.

You can check what the compiler tells you when you incorrectly try this:

`Vector3 whatever = Vector3.up * Vector3.zero;`
-> `Operator '*' cannot be applied to to operands of type Vector3 and Vector3`

Also, not a big deal just for one line or for a spare operation, but for the sake of efficiency it makes sense to multiply all your scalars first, and then the resultant scalar with your vector to reduce the amount of operations.

Comment: Of what use is Dot or Cross for the asker in their use case? Dot especially is of spurious use. `Dot(transform.forward * a, transform.right * b)` is always going to result in zero, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers focus on what operators there are between two `Vector3`, none of them make really sense in your use case though.

From what you have it looks to me like actually you rather simply want `+` not `*` like

```
Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * currentDir.y + transform.right * currentDir.x) * walkSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;
```

Comment: While the other two answers are technically correct and may be helpful to future visitors, this answer appears to most accurately address the needs of the asker. Insightful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vector3.Scale - if that is what you need.

> Multiplies two vectors component-wise.
>
> Every component in the result is a component of a multiplied by the
> same component of b.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html